# Google Fonts API and Polymer: CORS issues

Tags: webfonts, polymer, google-font-api

I've been playing with [Polymer](http://polymer-project.org) recently and finally I think I have my head around the shadow boundary, at least to the extent that I know where I need to include link tags to make my CSS work.

This is fine and dandy but I can't use Google fonts. If I use an `@import` inside my stylesheet, then as soon as that stylesheet is included in a Polymer custom element I get CORS issues:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro:400,700. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:64000' is therefore not allowed access
```

There's an XMLHttpRequest involved here, probably because of how Polymer fetches resources and custom elements in the first place, which I suppose is axing the header mentioned in the error message.

However, if I only use the link method

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This doesn't cross the shadow boundary, and I still don't get my fonts.

Am I missing something obvious? How do I get Google fonts inside the shadow DOM? I tried downloading the zip file from Google Fonts itself but I only got TTF files.

Comment: Note that I can't seem to reproduce the issue with the link method - I guess that's what happens when you let your brain relax a while. Accepted answer is really useful, however, so I left it for others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What we typically do with fonts on the Polymer team is to create an HTML import that loads the font(s), and include that import as a dependency in your element's import. This puts the font definitions in the main document (so they can be used by any components) but also guarantees that the fonts will be available in your element's shadow dom.

Here's a quick example: http://jsbin.com/cefawali/1/edit

We do this with the RobotoDraft font. Here's the import: https://github.com/Polymer/font-roboto/blob/master/roboto.html

The [other approach](http://jsbin.com/fobejuci/1/edit) is to use `no-shim` and use `@import`:

```
<polymer-element>
<template>
 <style no-shim>
    @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro:400,700');
 </style>
...
```

**Note** There's currently a [bug](https://github.com/Polymer/platform-dev/issues/15) preventing this latter approach from working.

Comment: After an amount of messing around I cannot actually seem to reproduce my original issue. It works if I use the link in the document's own head! However, this is definitely good advice - and once no-shim is working again I think it will be a good way of separating CSS and markup properly once again. Most grateful.

Comment: It's still probably useful to use an HTML import so that components can explicitly declare it as a dependency while still benefiting from [de-duping](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#loadlibs).